# Duplicated log4j output during JUnit test

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, log4j

We have implemented a `log4j` console logger with the following `log4j.properties` file:

```
# Set root logger level to info and its only appender to default.
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, default

# default is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.default=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# default uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.default.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.default.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error
```

While executing the program normally in eclipse everything works fine, but when we start one of our `JUnit` tests, which also calls parts of the program with loggers, we always get duplicated logger output on the eclipse console. Despite that it doesn't influence our tests it would still be much easier for us to read the logger informations if they wouldn't be duplicated.

This is how we configure `log4j` for the first time use:

```
public ConsoleTextLogger(final Class<?> clazz) {
    super();
    this.logger = Logger.getLogger(clazz.getName());
    // loads the configuration file and configures the log4j logging framework
    if (LOGGERLOGGER == null) {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("log4j.properties");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(url);
    }
}
```

This is how we use the logger in one of our JUnit classes:

```
public class TestClass1 {
   @BeforeClass
   public static void setup() {
      TestSetupUtility.loadPath();
   }

   // TESTS
}
```

`TestSetupUtility` sets everything up we need for the different tests.

```
public class TestSetupUtility {
  /**
   * Class specific Logger.
   */
  protected static final ConsoleTextLogger LOGGER = new ConsoleTextLogger(TestSetupUtility.class);
}
```

Any ideas of what could cause such a phenomena and why only when running `JUnit` tests?
Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.

Comment: There is only a single log4j.properties file? Can you add code showing how log4j is configured in the tests?

Comment: @Mark No it's the only `log4j.properties file` ... I have added additional informations if you need anything else just ask ;)

Comment: In your test setup maybe you should instantiate the logger after loading the properties.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I found the problem now ... During a JUnit test I switched the logger level to `Level.DEBUG` and the method which was responsible for switching the logger level called the following method `BasicConfigurator.configure();` which creates a second basic logger. After removing this method call the duplicated logging was gone.